# ViewPager + PagerTabStrip inside ScrollView. It's possible?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-scrollview

That's the idea:
A ViewPager(Horizontal) insde ScrollView(Vertical). ViewPager will show diferents fragments depending on the tab, and has vertical scroll to show all fragment view on the screen.

But the thing is ViewPager isn't showing the fragment entirely, it doesn't expand the fragment's height or the ScrollView height.

There's a way to expand dinamically the ViewPager height or the ScrollView height to show completely the fragment using scroll?

```
<ScrollView>
 <ImageView/>
 <ViewPager>        
    <PagerTabStrip/>
 </ViewPager>
 <Button/> </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than putting the ScrollView outside the ViewPager, instead you should make any views that populate the ViewPager (and need to scroll) ScrollViews.

This way each view (in the view pager) will have it's own vertical scroll offset that will be remembered as you page through the views.

Comment: That was my first thought, but i need to show the imageview(coverflow gallery in the future) and make it scrollable on each ViewPager's view.

Comment: @Zeltakun as long as you're not trying to put a vertically scrolling view inside another vertically scrolling view (whether indirectly or otherwise), then it should work fine. Presumably the cover-flow gallery in question is horizontally scrolling.